# How to crash application even in non-GUI mode using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I want to perform load testing using JMeter to check where we are getting an application crash.

When I apply 1500 users and run the test using non-GUI mode I got heap space error but cannot crash my application.

Answer (score 1):

1. As of current JMeter version (JMeter 5.0) default maximum heap space allocated to JVM is 1 gigabyte which is fine for tests development and/or debugging but might be not enough for stress test. Haven't you seen this message in the terminal window when you launch JMeter:

   ```
   ================================================================================
   Don't use GUI mode for load testing !, only for Test creation and Test debugging.
   For load testing, use NON GUI Mode:
      jmeter -n -t [jmx file] -l [results file] -e -o [Path to web report folder]
   & increase Java Heap to meet your test requirements:
      Modify current env variable HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m" in the jmeter batch file
   Check : https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
   ================================================================================
   ```

   you can increase heap space allocated to JMeter to the required value. See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for more recommendations on how to perform JMeter fine tuning for high loads
2. Ensure that JMeter has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. as if JMeter will lack resources - it will not be able to execute requests fast enough resulting in lesser load than you expect. If you don't have a monitoring system in place you can consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
3. It might be the case one machine will not be enough to put your application on knees, if you reach hardware limit on JMeter side but your application is still not loaded/overloaded - you will have to go for [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
4. And last (however it should be first) recommendation: your test plan should represent real user activity as hammering login page doesn't make sense. Your test must represent real-life application usage with 100% accuracy, otherwise you will not be able to state that your application can support 1500 users.